# getting error on jwt.io when trying to get access_token

Tags: aws-lambda, oauth-2.0, jwt, amazon-cognito, google-photos-api

i'm configuring Oauth2 between google photosapi and aws cognito.
when trying to get access_token in jwt.io from client id and client secret,
i'm keep getting the following error on the jwt.io url when pressing on the view hosted UI ->
https://jwt.io/#error_description=username+attribute+mapping+required&error=invalid_request
all fields are mapped correctly so i dont undestand what is the malfunction here.
[image]

does anyone have any idea how to solve it?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

i solve the issue by writing correctly the scope.
Hosted UI
[image]

should be matched in the scope under identity provider: Google
[image]

my question now is -> if i got access_token and i'm using it as header ->

```
{
            "Authorization": "Bearer ey...XMQ"

}
```

why i'm keep getting this error message ->

```
"error": {
"code": 401,
"message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
}
```